# having problems packaging my game in UE 5.3.2

Tags: unreal-5

I have tried to package my game and it doesn't work.

I am unsure how to proceed any further. It was a week ago or so that I started trying to package my game in 5.3.2 but that didn't work. Upon investigation, I discovered that when I use a game instance upon reopening the UE editor, it crashes. So I have been working very hard to replace game instance with save game. But tonight just for kicks. I tried to package my, without game instance. And the same cryptic error that happens every when the game instance crashes the editor happened in package.

I had thought this error is caused by presence of game instance so I was just testing to see ok what if there is no game instance would my game package, sadly the answer is NO.

Both my crash log and the package error log share the same cryptic error whose meaning have not been able to find in all my searches online.

The error is:

```
Assertion failed: Linker [File:D:\build++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp] [Line: 2152]
```

So I went and downloaded the debugging symbols. so this time the package failing log is much more explicit, here is the [complete log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ALs09cpq9AXe7RX7KE2abcDT6Ipz6sbe/view?usp=drive_link).

The [full crash log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NuOuLOSsQCy0sIIX6u076dlEuR5__5gihrbVuSjla6w/edit) after using game instance upon reopening the UE editor.

Comment: So I went and downloaded the debugging symbols. so this time the package failing log is much more explicit, here is the complete log.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ALs09cpq9AXe7RX7KE2abcDT6Ipz6sbe/view?usp=drive_link